# Onclick show/hide - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working a very simple program that show the solution of the problem when the user click on the solution link. I'm trying to do this without using jQuery.

So the first thing that I did was to add a click to my `p`. But now I'm lost and I don't know how to display the solution.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

```js
var solutionLink = document.querySelectorAll("p.solutionLink");

function openSolution(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('.solution').nextSibling.style.display = "block";
}

for(var i=0; i< solutionLink.length; i++){
  var solutions = solutionLink[i];
  solutions.addEventListener('click', openSolution, false);
}
```

```css
.solutions {display:none;}
```

```html
<p>This problem #1</p>

<p class="solutionLink">Click here to see solution</p>

<div class="solutions">
  This is the solution to problem #1
</div>

<p>This problem #2</p>

<p class="solutionLink">Click here to see solution</p>

<div class="solutions">
  This is the solution to problem #2
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, put a `.hidden` class with your `<div>`s, and remove/add this class when `.solutionLink` is clicked.

Comment: Why without jQuery?  jQuery exists to make your life so much easier.

Comment: there's gotta be a duplicate for cases of `getElementsByClassName('classname').propertythatonlyexistsonsingleelements`

Comment: plus, `getElementsByClassName` wants a classname, not a selector.

Comment: there's a reason `getElementsByClassName` is named `getElementsByClassName` rather than `getElementByClassName`

Comment: @ErikPhilips I was reading that is a good idea to learn vanilla javascript, and here I'm trying.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Because you don't have to bloat up your code unnecessarily. For small pieces of js it is a really unnecessary dependency. And once you know vanilla js a bit better, jQuery doesn't make you that much more productive.

Comment: @SourceOverflow  Productivity isn't the only thing it provides,  Cross-Browser compatibility, Maintainability etc.  There is a reason we don't program in Machine Language these days.  Javascript is the Machine Language for Browsers.  jQuery, Knockout, React/Redux, Angular all from all points of view, just better frameworks to use.  Deep dive Learning JS is like learning Machine Code, at this point in time, it provides almost no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var solutionLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".solutionLink");

for (var i = 0; i < solutionLinks.length; i++) {
  solutionLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<p>This problem #1</p>
<p class="solutionLink">Click here to see solution</p>
<div class="hidden">
  This is the solution to problem #1
</div>

<p>This problem #2</p>
<p class="solutionLink">Click here to see solution</p>
<div class="hidden">
  This is the solution to problem #2
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is your css selector: The class `solutions` is really called `solution`.

Next I would recommend making use of the [**data-attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). This way you can change your DOM-structure and don't have to change any js. Alternatively I would at least wrap every solution in its own container.

Below is a (in my opinion) nice implementation, but I still want to outline some problems with your js:

- `getElementsByClassName('.solution')̀  should be`getElementsByClassName('solution')̀ , since the `.` is not part of the class name
- `getElementsByClassName` returns elementS, as in more than one. You will have to access them using `[0]`

```js
var solutionLink = document.querySelectorAll("p.solutionLink");

function openSolution(){
  document.getElementById(this.dataset.target).style.display = "block";
}

for(var i=0; i< solutionLink.length; i++){
  var solutions = solutionLink[i];
  solutions.addEventListener('click', openSolution, false);
}
```

```css
.solution {display:none;}
```

```html
<p>This problem #1</p>

<p class="solutionLink" data-target="sol1">Click here to see solution</p>

<div id="sol1" class="solution">
  This is the solution to problem #1
</div>

<p>This problem #2</p>

<p class="solutionLink" data-target="sol2">Click here to see solution</p>

<div id="sol2" class="solution">
  This is the solution to problem #2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you currently attempting to retrieve the `nextSibling` of the very element that you wish to display (the `textNode`) ?
Using the `event Object` `target` (the `p.solutionLink`), access the adjacent `elementNode` (`div.solution`) . According to your code the follow solution should work for you.

```
function openSolution(event){
  event.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
```

P.S why is your CSS selector plural `.solutions` ?

Comment: Thank you! I'm testing your code and gt this console error "Cannot read property 'nextElementSibling' of undefined"

Comment: Here is a working example. (with some  added features) https://codepen.io/pablo-tavarez/pen/qVqGzX

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.